# Wordpress media images are broken

Tags: wordpress

i have using WordPress version 4.4 , I have moved the files to another server.
My WordPress Library images are broken check my screen [My Error Page Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od6Mo.jpg)

Comment: your url's in your database are probably still linking to your old server. Log in to your phpmyadmin and search & replace the old urls with the new ones.

Comment: i have already changed url , Its all Working fine expert my images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the images cannot be found on this server, you have two options

1. Re-upload all images to your new server through wp-admin
2. upload your uploads folder to your new server (located in yoursitename/wp-content/uploads)

Comment: I have checked images files in FTP, all files is there Kindly check my image url http://angleritech.co.in/CMS/intuit/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/dubai-city.jpg

Comment: This is very strange, please try and re-upload them?

Comment: Is there any way to remove these entries and re upload?

Comment: @SidhinThomas can you explain more? I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: The media section is full of broken entires because a lot of media was deleted directly from server.

Comment: Okay so re-upload all images into your uploads folder and it should fix it, failing that, delete all images from the gallery on WordPress and re-import them.